# I might have some Korean letter enconding issue.

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, web-crawler

I am using python 3.6 and pycharm 2016.2 and trying to crawl an web site.

In the category of "보험사고이력 정보 : 내차 피해" (which includes the fifth tables), I tried to crawl the data if one of "p tag" has "- 사고일자" in its contents.

Below is my code. It keeps returning nothing.

Please help.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import re

popup_insurance = "http://www.bobaedream.co.kr/mycar/popup/mycarChart_B.php?car_number=35%EB%91%908475&tbl=cyber&cno=651451"
res = urllib.request.urlopen(popup_insurance)
html = res.read()
soup_insurance = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
insurance_content_table = soup_insurance.find_all('table')

elem = soup_insurance.find("p", text="보험사고이력 정보 : 내차 피해")
while elem.string != "보험사고이력 정보 : 타차 가해":
    if "사고일자" in elem.next_sibling:
        print(elem.next_sibling)

    elem = elem.next_sibling

    if elem is None:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You should loop through `elem.next_sibling`, `NavigableString`'s can be odd sometimes:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import re

popup_insurance = "http://www.bobaedream.co.kr/mycar/popup/mycarChart_B.php?car_number=35%EB%91%908475&tbl=cyber&cno=651451"
res = urllib.request.urlopen(popup_insurance)
html = res.read()
soup_insurance = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
insurance_content_table = soup_insurance.find_all('table')

elem = soup_insurance.find("p", text="보험사고이력 정보 : 내차 피해")
while elem.string != "보험사고이력 정보 : 타차 가해":
    for string in elem.next_sibling:
        if "사고일자" in string:
            print(elem.next_sibling.string.strip())

    elem = elem.next_sibling

    if elem is None:
        break
```

I am assuming (since you did not provide expected output) that you wanted the Accident Date / Repair cost bit.

This is nowhere near perfect or even elegant, I'm almost sure this can be done with just the for loop.